# Compare array of objects to array of ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jQuery, I would like to use an array of ids to find the objects inside the `allObjects` array that have the matching `Id` value.

```
var arrayOfIds = [1, 4, 5];

var allObjects = [{"Id":"1", "name":"aa"},{"Id":"2", "name":"bb"} ,{"Id":"3", "name":"cc"} ,{"Id":"4", "name":"dd"}, {"Id":"5", "name":"ee"}, {"Id":"6", "name":"ff"}, {"Id":"7", "name":"gg"}, {"Id":"8", "name":"hh"}, {"Id":"9", "name":"ii"}];
```

The result would equal:

```
[{"Id":"1", "name":"aa"}, {"Id":"4", "name":"dd"}, {"Id":"5", "name":"ee"}]
```

So far, I can only use the following to extract an individual object:

```
var result = $.grep(arrayOfIds, function(e) { return e.Id == 3; });
```

I feel as though the answer might be achieved by amending the above $.grep query somehow but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter `allObjects` and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the objects `Id` property is in `arrayOfIds`:

```
allObjects.filter(x=> arrayOfIds.includes(Number(x.Id)))
```

See [demo on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cexese/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: According to MDN, includes is not yet supported in IE, if that is a concern.

Comment: @Taplar There's a polyfill for it.

Answer (score 0):

Best is you transform the array to an object itself:

```
function atoo(a)
{
  var i, obj;

  obj = {};

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  {
    obj[a[i].Id] = a[i];
  }

  return obj;
}
```

You can now access all items in the array through the object by simply addressing them as an index:

```
obj["4"]
```

returns the correct object that is also stored in the array under `a[3]`.

There is no jQuery involved which should be considered a feature because it is a general solution to all kinds of these problems.

Using a filter (as in `Array.prototype.filter()`) is easier to write but also incurs in performance problems when you access the items very often or the array is very large. The above solution relies on the internal implementation of the object referencing which is as fast as you can wish for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method like following.

```
var arrayOfIds = [1, 4, 5];
var allObjects = [{ "Id": "1", "name": "aa" }, { "Id": "2", "name": "bb" }, { "Id": "3", "name": "cc" }, { "Id": "4", "name": "dd" }, { "Id": "5", "name": "ee" }, { "Id": "6", "name": "ff" }, { "Id": "7", "name": "gg" }, { "Id": "8", "name": "hh" }, { "Id": "9", "name": "ii" }];
var result = $(allObjects).filter(function() { return arrayOfIds.indexOf(+this.Id) > -1 }).get();
```

Comment: Don't use `+` operator to turn a string into a number, it makes code unreadable. Also, why are you using `.indexOf()` when there is `.includes()` method?

Comment: Better to not use +, but I don't find any problem with `indexOf()`. @Gothdo